# How to toggle image location in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm trying to make it so if you click an image it changes its source and if you click it again it changes back.

```
<img 
    src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/laughing-smiley-face-clip-art-smiley-face-clip-art10.jpeg" 
    longdesc="http://smileyfaceplace.weebly.com/uploads/6/9/7/1/6971266/9884860_orig.jpg"
    width="400"
    id="smiley"
    onClick = "toggleHide('smiley');"

/>
```

Script:

```
function toggleHide(ImgId) {
        var image = document.getElementById(ImgId).src;
        document.getElementById(ImgId).src = document.getElementById(ImgId).longdesc;
        document.getElementById(ImgId).longdesc = image;
        alert(document.getElementById(ImgId).longdesc);
    }
```

Am I doing this all wrong?  When I run the code below, the swapping does work but the alternate image comes up as undefined.

I'm using the longdesc attribute because it seems benign and is a valid attribute but I'd rather use my own madeup attribute for this kind of thing if possible.

edit: Thanks fellas it works now:

```
<img 
    src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/laughing-smiley-face-clip-art-smiley-face-clip-art10.jpeg" 
    altsrc="http://smileyfaceplace.weebly.com/uploads/6/9/7/1/6971266/9884860_orig.jpg"
    width="400"
    id="smiley"
    onClick = "toggleHide('smiley');"

/>
```

Script:

```
    function toggleHide(ImgId){ 
        var image = document.getElementById(ImgId);
        var oldsrc = image.src;
        image.src = image.getAttribute('altsrc');
        image.setAttribute('altsrc', oldsrc);
        //alert(document.getElementById(ImgId).longdesc);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is no property called `longdesc` for `img`, you need to read it as an attribute.

Also you can just pass the image element reference to `toggleHide` so that you can avoid multiple calls to `document.getElementById()`

```js
function toggleHide(el) {
  var image = el.src;
  el.src = el.getAttribute('longdesc');
  el.setAttribute('longdesc', image);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/laughing-smiley-face-clip-art-smiley-face-clip-art10.jpeg" longdesc="http://smileyfaceplace.weebly.com/uploads/6/9/7/1/6971266/9884860_orig.jpg" width="400" id="smiley" onClick="toggleHide(this);" />
```

Note: Even though you have tagged it using jQuery, since your solution didn't use jQuery, I haven't used jQuery either.

---

A jQuery-ish solution will be

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.toggle-hide').click(function() {
    var image = this.src,
      $this = $(this);
    this.src = $this.data('toggle-src');
    $this.data('toggle-src', image);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/laughing-smiley-face-clip-art-smiley-face-clip-art10.jpeg" data-toggle-src="http://smileyfaceplace.weebly.com/uploads/6/9/7/1/6971266/9884860_orig.jpg" width="400" class="toggle-hide" />
```

Comment: Nice, I will use "this" as the argument :)

Comment: The JQuery version is also much nicer, thank you for this reply Arun.

Comment: It does exist, it's just camel-cased (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534132(VS.85).aspx). But anyway, they seem to be trying hard to get rid of it for good.

Answer (score 4):

The `longdesc` property needs to be camelCased:

```js
function toggleHide(ImgId){
        var image = document.getElementById(ImgId).src;
        document.getElementById(ImgId).src = document.getElementById(ImgId).longDesc;
        document.getElementById(ImgId).longDesc = image;
        //alert(document.getElementById(ImgId).longdesc);
    }
```

```html
<img 
    src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/laughing-smiley-face-clip-art-smiley-face-clip-art10.jpeg" 
    longdesc="http://smileyfaceplace.weebly.com/uploads/6/9/7/1/6971266/9884860_orig.jpg"
    width="400"
    id="smiley"
    onClick = "toggleHide('smiley');"

/>
```

---

### Better Approach

But again, it's much better to use a custom `data-` attribute for this:

```js
function toggleHide(ImgId) {
  var img = document.getElementById(ImgId);
  var tmp = img.src;
  img.src = img.getAttribute('data-alt');
  img.setAttribute('data-alt', tmp);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/laughing-smiley-face-clip-art-smiley-face-clip-art10.jpeg" 
     data-alt="http://smileyfaceplace.weebly.com/uploads/6/9/7/1/6971266/9884860_orig.jpg" 
     width="400" id="smiley" onClick="toggleHide('smiley');" />
```

Comment: I'm new to JS, are custom data attributes a thing typically used?  I noticed it seems to be supported by the JQ syntax.

Comment: They actually came to life with HTML5, and now are widely supported and encouraged to use in such situations. You'll see numerous jQ plugins use them.

Comment: super cool, thank you Shomz.  I regret I don't have more upvotes to give.